# Oracle: How to boost query by removing Subquery into Conditions or Join to same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have view called Employee_All.

This bring data from two (one to many) tables using join where some many record are put into single row and show in employee all. `One` has 30,000 records and `many` has double to `One`.

Following simple Query Takes: 1 sec to return 50 records

```
SELECT x.*, (SELECT 'NOIFS' FROM DUAL) as TYPE  FROM Employee_ALL x
```

When i add condition and it return 50 records in 1.81 seconds

```
SELECT x.*, (SELECT 'NOIFS' FROM DUAL) as TYPE  FROM Employee_ALL x 
WHERE (x.endDate > sysdate-90 OR x.endDate is null) OR x.lastUpdated >= sysdate-30
fetch first 50 rows only
```

Now there is subquery and this returns 50 records in: 4.14 seconds

```
SELECT x.*, (SELECT USERID FROM Employee_ALL z WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEEID)=x.leaderEmployeeId ) as managersuserid, (SELECT 'NOIFS' FROM DUAL) as TYPE  
FROM Employee_ALL x 
WHERE (x.endDate > sysdate-90 OR x.endDate is null) OR x.lastUpdated >= sysdate-30
fetch first 50 rows only
```

Is there any way to adjust last query in the way that it return results in seconds as i need to run this query against 30,000 records? (It is taking nearly 10-15 minutes to load data) any more suggestion

Sample Data like:

```
EmpID ManagerEmpID NAME            UserID
1       2          Harry           Har
2                  Garry Manager   Gar
3       2          Cherry          Char
```

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Why would you need to use `UPPER()` on an "id" column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It appears old code.

Comment: @jarlh: How can we apply left join in above situation? I am  getting column ambigious issue

Comment: if you make a left join with both tables, qualify each column

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: Is it correct -> SELECT x.*, y.USERID as u,
(SELECT 'NOIFS' FROM DUAL) as TYPE  FROM Employee_ALL x 
LEFT JOIN Employee_ALL y  ON y.leaderEmployeeId = x.EMPLOYEEID
WHERE (x.endDate > sysdate-90 OR x.endDate is null) OR x.lastUpdated >= sysdate-30
fetch first 50 rows only

Comment: but why are you  making a query from dual to put the string 'NOIFS' ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: That is required in code. But above query is not giving expected results. I need to do it different way. (

Comment: can you provide a data model and some results to see what exactly are you expecting as result ?

Comment: I would edit the question and provide some examples, thereby I might help you

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: I have updated a bit of model

Comment: @fatherazrael , I updated the answer. Let me know whether is what you expect, I removed the last filter part because I did not add the lastUpdated field to my model

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: That manager USER ID shall have GAR (Manager's user id). This is missing and coming null. Even in your example too

Comment: that is normal, because the condition in the case does not match. Updated answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding the whole data model and what are the expected results, it is quite difficult. I would use this query:

```
SELECT x.* , 
case when UPPER(x.EMPLOYEEID)=z.leaderEmployeeId then z.userid else null end 
as managersuserid, 
'NOIFS' as TYPE  
FROM Employee_ALL x left join Employee_ALL z on ( x.EMPLOYEEID = z.EMPLOYEEID ) 
WHERE (x.endDate > sysdate-90 OR x.endDate is null) OR x.lastUpdated >= sysdate-30
```

Using your data model example I build this

```
SQL> create table Employee_ALL ( EMPLOYEEID number, managerempid number, name varchar2(100) , userid varchar2(100) );

insert into Employee_ALL  values ( 1 ,2 , 'Harry' , 'Har' );
insert into Employee_ALL  values ( 2 ,null , 'Robert' , 'Rob' );
insert into Employee_ALL  values ( 3 ,null , 'Jim' , 'Jim' );
insert into Employee_ALL  values ( 4 ,2 , 'Frank' , 'Fra' );
Table created.

SQL> SQL>
1 row created.

SQL>
1 row created.

SQL>
1 row created.

SQL>

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

SQL> alter table Employee_ALL add end_date date ;

Table altered.

SQL> update Employee_ALL set end_date = sysdate where EMPLOYEEID = 1 ;

update Employee_ALL set end_date = sysdate - 91 where employeeid = 4;

update Employee_ALL set end_date = sysdate where end_date is null;
1 row updated.

SQL> SQL>
1 row updated.

SQL> SQL>

2 rows updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

 SELECT x.* ,
  2        case when UPPER(x.EMPLOYEEID)=z.ManagerEmpID then z.userid else null end as managersuserid,
  3       'NOIFS' as TYPE
  4  FROM Employee_ALL x left join Employee_ALL z on ( x.EMPLOYEEID = z.EMPLOYEEID )
  5* WHERE (x.end_date > sysdate-90 OR x.end_date is null)

EMPLOYEEID MANAGEREMPID NAME       USERID     END_DATE MANAGERSUS TYPE
---------- ------------ ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- -----
         1            2 Harry      Har        20200710            NOIFS
         2              Robert     Rob        20200710            NOIFS
         3              Jim        Jim        20200710            NOIFS

SQL>
```

If I update the manager field

```
SQL> update Employee_ALL set MANAGEREMPID=2 where employeeid=2 ;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>  SELECT x.* ,
       case when UPPER(x.EMPLOYEEID)=z.ManagerEmpID then z.userid else null end as managersuserid,
      'NOIFS' as TYPE
 FROM Employee_ALL x left join Employee_ALL z on ( x.EMPLOYEEID = z.EMPLOYEEID )
 WHERE (x.end_date > sysdate-90 OR x.end_date is null)
 /  2    3    4    5    6

EMPLOYEEID MANAGEREMPID NAME       USERID     END_DATE MANAGERSUS TYPE
---------- ------------ ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- -----
         1            2 Harry      Har        20200710            NOIFS
         2            2 Robert     Rob        20200710 Rob        NOIFS
         3              Jim        Jim        20200710            NOIFS
```

Comment: We need Manager's user id. In above example. We need ManagerUs id i.e Har in Managerus field of EmployeeID 2 and 3

Comment: your condition to show userid is this UPPER(EMPLOYEEID)=x.leaderEmployeeId , so the leaderemployeeid is the same as employeeid for the employees that are managers

Comment: It appears all correct but why i am getting null :(